# Realize repeating notification at define date and time

Tags: android

I need to realize notifications for user  for example  1st September at 1pm,5 October at 1pm and so on.These events must be repeated every year. These dates already stored in application. I can make notification for example each half a hour with AlarmManager. But how to do repeating notifications in the define date and time. There are lot of similar topics, but I didn't find any appropriate solution. Can anybody help me with this question?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone:
I used one-shot alarm and in receiver for alarm restarted the alarm generating each time new date and time for my alarm.